# create grid view with devexpress asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress

I want to create a DevExpress grid view in an asp.net mvc 5 .But it did not display pagination, it had just the contents of the grid .How can i add the pagination to the grid?

Controller :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to DevExpress Extensions for ASP.NET MVC!";
    ViewData["Report"] = new Training.UI.Web.Reporting.XtraReport1();
    return View();
}
```

View :

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(
    settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "myGridView";
        settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "EtatCNFCPP", Action = "GridViewPart" };

        settings.Columns.Add("EntMatriculeFiscal");
        settings.Columns.Add("EntCodeCNSSCnrps");
        settings.Columns.Add("EntNom").SortOrder = DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.Ascending;

    }).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

Comment: There is the GridViewSettings.SettingsPager.Visible (https://documentation.devexpress.com/#aspnet/DevExpressWebPagerSettingsEx_Visibletopic) property to show or hide the pager. So, you can set the settings.SettingsPager.Visible property to false to hide the pager. Is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your grid view setting you can add this line to show the grid pagination.

```
settings.SettingsPager.PageSizeItemSettings.Visible = true;
```

You can refer on this link 
[DevExpress MVC Grid View - Data Paging and Scrolling](https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxGridViewDemos/PagingAndScrolling/Paging)

Answer (score -1):

In javascript Use the porperty  pagingEnabled: false